# shortcode passes custom post type name to pagetemplate

Tags: wordpress

i have a page template in place assigned to a page named cartoonbooks. the custom post type is also called cartoonbooks. how do i get the page to pass the customposttype to the pagetemplate    so that i can use the same template for different pages. i tried using shortcodes but unsuccessful ...plz help

functions.php

```
<?php
function my_shortcode_handler( $atts, $content = null ) {
    extract( shortcode_atts( array(
        'attr_1' => '',     
    // ...etc
    ), $atts ) );
return $attr_1;
}
add_shortcode( 'myshortcode', 'my_shortcode_handler' );
?>
```

page-books.php

```
<article>       
    <?php            
        //Define the loop based on arguments

        $loop = new WP_Query( $attr_1);

        //Display the contents

        while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
    ?>

        <?php the_content(); ?>

    <?php endwhile;?>       
  </article>
```

in the page i put the short code

```
[myshortcode attr_1="cartoonbooks"]
```

---

i updated my code still it doesn't work ...heres the new one

functions.php

```
function shortcode_handler( $atts, $content = null ) {
    extract( shortcode_atts( array(
        'posttype' => '',           
    // ...etc
    ), $atts ) );
return do_shortcode($posttype);
}
function register_my_shortcode(){
add_shortcode( 'shortcode', 'shortcode_handler' );
}
add_action('init','register_shortcode');
?>
```

page.php

```
<?php

    $args = do_shortcode($content); 

    //Define the loop based on arguments

    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );

    //Display the contents

    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
?>
      <div><?php the_title('')?></div>


<?php endwhile;?>
```

in the page called carttonbooks itself i put the code

```
[myshortcode posttype="cartoonbooks"]
```

in anothe page called adventurebooks i put code

```
[myshortcode posttype="adventurebooks"]
```

but the template doesn't take the posttype from the shortcod and display he content...plzhelp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok for those who may have this problem in future...i found the solution by test and trial method...and its very easy.

now say your posttype is books and the slug is books too so the archive page will be archive-books.

create a page with slug as books(slug os archive and page should be same) and add it to menu no need for any template it automatically grabs the archive-books content...so whatever styling u need put it on the archive page

Answer (score 0):

In wordpress for template file to call shortcode we use`do_shortcode()`
try this:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[myshortcode "cartoonbooks"]'); ?>
```

[Know more](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/do_shortcode)

Comment: if i put the above code in the template then when the posttype changes to say 'adventurebooks' the template will still show cartoonbooks content as the do_shortcode has cartoonbooks assigned to it

Answer (score 0):

Why do any of this. It seems to be a waste.
Check the post type in the template. http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_type

```
if(get_post_type( $post ) == 'cartoonbooks') {
    //Your special post type template code
} else {
    // Your normal template code
}
```